# getting "This page isn’t working right now" in laravel login page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have starter laravel app, when I access the login page, shows to me "This page isn’t working right now", I don't see any errors in my code
my `loginController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }
    public function index(){
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        dd($request->remember);
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
            return back()->with('status', 'Invalid login details');
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

login route in `web.php` file :

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove these lines:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth']);
}
```

Because you force for auth middleware.
You should not add auth middleware to the login page.

Comment: Ah, good catch, but perhaps explain a bit why this is causing the issue.

Comment: ahhhh, It's the 3rd day trying to fix this, for me, I'll change `auth` to `guest`, thank you very much

Comment: You add auth middleware in the login page. but the user is not logged in so the middleware redirects the users to the login page again and again the user is not logged inn. so it creates a redirection loop.

Comment: @waterloomatt , the laravel's middleware auto redirect to login page if it set to `auth`, in this code, I set a middleware `auth` to the login page, that means when I access the login page it'll redirect me to login again, it will go to infinite redirections, the browser shows 'example.com redirected you too many times.'  hope you getting me